# How to find Boot Sequence or order via Windows Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

everyone,

I am trying to get specific information about my system BIOs. My company is running a system security audit, and they want to make sure that I have a BIOS password in place (we do). I also want to show them that we have disabled dual-boot.

What I have attempted to do was run System Info, which would give the boot device. I also ran manage-bde -status, which corresponds to bitlocker.

Any help?

I tried SystemInfo, as well as Get-WmiObject -msinfo, but those commands don't show that the BIOS is password protected and/or that dual boot is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The best best is going to be using `Get-WmiObject` (or better yet, `Get-CIMInstance`) but you're going to have to find the correct CIM class for your machine; companies like Dell and HP for example will often include their own CIM classes for managing things like the BIOS so there most likely won't be a single default class that'll give you the information you're looking for.

You can get a look at what's under the hood in WMI/CIM with `Get-CimClass -ClassName *` but it's probably going to be a lot easier to use a graphical WMI/CIM explorer tool like the one made by [Sapien Technologies](https://www.sapien.com/software/cimexplorer) to explore the available classes on your particular machine. You might need to look for a namespace created by the hardware manufacturer.

I wish there was an easier answer but the fact is that hardware manufacturers are notorious for making things proprietary and difficult. Give the CMI Explorer a shot, there's a decent chance you'll find what you're looking for (if it's been made available as a CIM class in Windows)